# Query Super Type and Subtype in Mysql

Tags: database-theory, databases, relational-algebra

Assuming I have a schema depicted in the image [image: here], showing relationships(specialization) between Staffs, Academic Staffs and Non Academic Staffs. Is it possible to have a query that retrieves the department and level if the staff is an academic staff or state and unit if it is a non academic staff based on type attribute in the staff entity?

Comment: This seems to be a programming question, so off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

For MS-SQL (MySQL should be very similar):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4f530/1

Schema:

`CREATE TABLE Staff(
  id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  type varchar(45)
)
CREATE TABLE Acad(
  id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  dep varchar(45)
)
CREATE TABLE Non(
  id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  unit varchar(45)
)
INSERT INTO Staff(id, type) Values (1, 'acad'), (2, 'non')
INSERT INTO Acad Values (1, 'department')
INSERT INTO Non Values (2, 'unit')`

Query:

`SELECT *
FROM Staff S
LEFT JOIN Acad A ON S.id = A.id AND s.type = 'acad'
LEFT JOIN Non N ON S.id = N.id AND s.type = 'non'`

I don't think you can get anything conceptually better without using T-SQL (loops and dynamic code generation).